# Performing transformation with xslt 2.0 how do I get quoted values separated with a delimiter?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation, saxon

I have an xml to transform:

```
<root>
  <item name="first" />
  <item name="second" />
  <item name="third" />
</root>
```

What I want to get is a string where every value is quoted and values are separated (order does not matter):

```
"first" , "second" , "third"
```

My question is how do I achieve this using xslt 2.0 properly?

Here is my solution that does not work as expected.
So my co-question is - why it is not?

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns="urn:my.name.space"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text/json"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:value-of select="item/@name" separator=" , "/>
    <xsl:text> :: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="item/ns:quotedString(@name)" separator=" , "/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="ns:quotedString">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:variable name="quote">&quot;</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, $input, $quote)"/>
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me:

```
first , second , third :: "second""third""first"
```

Note the separator is missing if I call my quoting function.

I apply transformation using Saxon-B 9.1.0.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to join a bunch of strings.

**XPath for ... in ...**

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(for $i in item return concat('&quot;', $i/@name, '&quot;'), ' , ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

`<string-join>` joins the quotated strings of each `item/@name`. The params of `<string-join>` are strings.

---

**Function call "ns:quotedString"**

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:value-of select="item/ns:quotedString(@name)" separator=" , "/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="ns:quotedString">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:variable name="quote">&quot;</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="concat($quote, $input, $quote)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

This will answer your question about *why is it not working*. See the `<xsl:sequence>` as last statement in function. The `@separator` only works, if the `<xsl:value select="...">` statement returns a sequence, in your case the return value is a single textnode.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a text node and [adjacent text nodes in the sequence are merged into a single text node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-simple-content). Have it return a sequence.

So change `xsl:value` of to `xsl:sequence` in your function...

```
<xsl:function name="ns:quotedString">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:variable name="quote">&quot;</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:sequence select="concat($quote, $input, $quote)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

My preference is to just send the sequence to the function...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ns="urn:my.name.space"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text/json"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:value-of select="item/@name" separator=" , "/>
    <xsl:text> :: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns:quotedString(item/@name)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="ns:quotedString">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',
      string-join($input,'&quot;, &quot;'),
      '&quot;')"/>
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Disclaimer: I don't have Saxon-B 9.1.0.8. to test with. I used Saxon-HE 9.5.1.7. to test.*

Comment: "Your function returns a string" is wrong, it returns a text node. If it returned a string then the expression `<xsl:value-of select="item/ns:quotedString(@name)" separator=" , "/>` would do what the poster wants. It doesn't work as https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-simple-content mandates "Adjacent text nodes in the sequence are merged into a single text node.".

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thanks for the clarification. I'll update my answer.